# Does a ClickOnce Application deploy to a FDCC locked down computer?

Tags: security, clickonce

We are looking to publish a ClickOnce application to a large Active Directory network which has to abide by the [FDCC](http://nvd.nist.gov/fdcc/fdcc_faq.cfm#1) (Federal Desktop Core Configuration) which is an OMB-mandated security configuration.

Does anyone have experience with this security configuration and ClickOnce applications?  The application requires the ability to read a file the logged in user has access to.

We are also concerned with extra security setting being placed in the future that may stop the ClickOnce application from working.

How robust is the ClickOnce method for deployment when you start to lock down the computer?
What settings *must* be in place for a ClickOnce to function?

Thank you,
Keith

edit:
I am also asking this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841825/does-a-clickonce-application-deploy-to-a-fdcc-locked-down-computer) since it kind of rides both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This presentation](http://nvd.nist.gov/scap/workshop/06Microsoft-Dave-Dixon-NIST.pdf) looks to say that VS2005 ClickOnce is not FIPS compliant.  It's a little hard to discern, but also maybe hints that VS2008 ClickOnce is.  See pages 3 and 4.

One thing in favor is that ClickOnce doesn't require local admin which is a no-no per FDCC.  This is an interesting question (+1) as I'm a .NET developer and deploy via ClickOnce quite often.  I'll keep looking and thinking on this.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It looks like click once will work.  I'll post what I find out during testing.

Answer (score 0):

[This FDCC blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/fdcc/archive/2008/11/12/fdcc-and-internet-explorer-7-part-2-impact-on-users.aspx) says explicitly that you can retire ActiveX controls and replace them with ClickOnce applications. Sorry, no help for any of your other questions.